# Variables javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a popup or prompt that when you input you name or whatever it says "Hello 'Name'! How are you today?" and I want to integrate that with the bubble letters I have going. So the input will change the bubble letters. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZjoaR

```
             <html>
               <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
               </head>
                    <body>
                <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
                         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

                      <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

               <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

                      <p id="demo"></p>

                 <script>
              function myFunction() {
            var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
                if (person != null) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
                    }
              }
               </script>

                </body>
             </html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";


          }
        }
       var myName = "edit";

       var red = [0, 100, 63];
       var orange = [40, 100, 60];
       var green = [75, 100, 40];
       var blue = [196, 77, 55];
       var purple = [280, 50, 60];
       var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

       drawName(myName, letterColors);

       if(10 < 3)
       {
       bubbleShape = 'square';
       }
       else
         {
        bubbleShape = 'circle';
         }

        bounceBubbles();
```

Comment: why not prompting `myName` ? `var myName = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your `drawName` function inside the function that prompts for a name.

```
function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";


  drawName(person, letterColors);


  }
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/IanRamosC/pen/EPXxGK)